# Does apr_table_get return a copy of the data?

Tags: apache, apr

If I call apr_table_get, do I get a copy of the data or just a pointer into the pool with the data?  (I want to change the value somehow and don't know if I would be crushing the pool data.)  Also, do I need to free the data.  The man page ([Table and Array Functions](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.2/group__apr__tables.html#g4db13e3915c6b9a3142b175d4c15d915)) doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

You get a copy of the pointer.    So, no.  If you want a copy of the data it points to, you need to make one.

This is why the return type is const!